# How to plot 3D figures correctly?

Tags: surfaces

When we always draw e.g. cylinder on the whiteboard, we get kind of this:
[image]

But naturally (assumed axes are perpendicular) when we have z-axis to the top and y-axis to the right, x-axis must point to us (from display) like this:

[image]

And when we look from another point so that x-axis is diagonally and z-axis to the top, then y-axis naturally can't be horizontal as on first image, it is a bit rotated.

My lecturer said these are two different kinds of plotting, but could not remember how are they called.

So here comes the question: what are the names of both these methods (natural and alternative plotting) and how to plot correctly in both situations?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isometric, Trimetric and Dimetric, these are all standard projections that are used for industrial purposes. ZulfiqarIII's link has all the info.